# How to get rid of dot in Chrome with sap_fiori_3 theme?

Tags: sapui5

I noticed an annoying dot next to the buttons in a table:
[image: Annoying dot next to button]

So far I found the following requirements for this to happen:

- Browser: Chrome (tested on v.111.0.5563.66)
- SAPUI5 theme: `sap_fiori_3`
- The column `width` next to it must be set to `100%`

So here is a minimal example to reproduce it in Chrome with:

```js
jQuery(function() {

  var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({});

  oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    width: "100%",
    label: new sap.m.Label({
      text: "Last Name"
    }),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
      text: "{lastName}"
    })
  }));

  // edit button
  oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    template: new sap.m.Button({
      icon: "sap-icon://edit"
    })
  }));

  // create some local data
  var list = [{
    lastName: "Zen"
  }, ];
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oModel.setData(list);

  oTable.setModel(oModel);
  oTable.bindRows("/");
  oTable.placeAt("content");

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Chrome Fiori Dot" />
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />
  <title>test</title>

  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_fiori_3' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.m'></script>


</head>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyone an idea what causes this dot and more importantly how to get rid of it?

Comment: Thusfar I found out that it's the resize function for the column (by inspecting the element on chrome). I haven't found how to disable or how to get rid of it.

Comment: i debugged a bit. Those are actually the dots '...' from text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis;
Why you get them there, i don't know.
BUT why would you not bootstrap with the official api? jQuery() is not part of the official documentation, or?

FYI question with correct booting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68319677/ui5-treetable-displays-flat-hierarchy-despite-using-hierarchy-annotations/68335785#68335785

Booting:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/fe12df2e338e43598977d09f3d191b7b.html

Comment: @BenediktKromer thanks for the info - I just reused some sample I found online, didn't notice the way it was set-up, I will adjust it soon